# if in while loop in C

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the following code:

```
while(tmp->next != NULL)
{
    if(tmp->code == (unsigned int)16777221)
    {
        CU_ASSERT_STRING_EQUAL("3GPP Zh", tmp->name);
    }
    if(strcmp((const char*)tmp->name, (const char*)"IUT-T Rs") == 0)
    {
        CU_ASSERT_EQUAL((unsigned int)16777235, tmp->code);
    }
    tmp = tmp->next;
}
```

What I want to do is this: once the code in the if structure is executed (that is to say, the **if condition is evaluated to true**), I don't want to execute it anymore in all the following while loops, how could I do this?

Comment: please be more specific/clear- on what you want

Comment: Don't cast to `const char*`, it's useless and meaningless. Also don't cast literals to `unsigned int`, use **16777221U** if you want an `unsigned int` literal.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Among all the while loops, if at a moment in a certain loop the if condition is evaluated to true, then in all the loops to come, I'd like to ignore this if structure, this is what I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int once = 0;

while(tmp->next != NULL)
{
    if(!once && tmp->code == (unsigned int)16777221)
    {
        once = 1;
        CU_ASSERT_STRING_EQUAL("3GPP Zh", tmp->name);
    }
    /* deal with subsequent if's in the same manner */
    tmp = tmp->next;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways of doing this:

1. shorter core, less efficient -> use a flag:

   ```
   int flag = 0;
   while(tmp->next != NULL)
   {
       if(flag && tmp->code == (unsigned int)16777221)
       {
           flag = 0;
           CU_ASSERT_STRING_EQUAL("3GPP Zh", tmp->name);
       }
       // some other code
       tmp = tmp->next;
   }
   ```
2. longer code, but a little more efficient ->split the code:

   ```
   void foo()
   {
     //code that needs to be executed
   }

   while(tmp->next != NULL)
   {
       if(tmp->code == (unsigned int)16777221)
       {
           CU_ASSERT_STRING_EQUAL("3GPP Zh", tmp->name);
           break;
       }
       foo();
    }
    while(tmp->next != NULL)
    {
       foo();
    }
   ```

The second way is more efficient because the common code has better cash locality and you don't have to execute the if statement for every iteration, when it's obvious the condition will not be true. Depending of how often the code is executed, it may be worth it...

Comment: If `foo()` doesn't get inlined, second code may be less efficient

Comment: Each method has its advantages, but I would much more prefer the first one.

Comment: `flag` can fully be removed from the 2nd snippet.

Comment: @V.Kravchenko: One *could* make `//code that needs to be executed` a marco ..., but one better won't.

Comment: @alk one could use `__forceinline`, but one better won't.